# WordPress function get_the_terms() returns 'Invalid taxonomy' error

Tags: plugin-development, functions

It seems that the function [get_the_terms( $id, $taxonomy )](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms) always returns an error if used outside of WordPress (i.e. integrated in PHP using [this method](http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website)). I believe some library might be required and should be included explicitly for this to work.

For example, the following code, where 284 is a valid post id and 'keyword' is a valid custom taxonomy...

```
$terms = get_the_terms( 284, 'keyword' );
var_dump($terms);
```

... works perfect when used in the admin UI (via plugin), but the same does give an 'Invalid taxonomy' error when used outside admin UI using [this method](http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website)

Any suggestions?

**Additional info:**

The taxonomy 'keyword' is registered at the hook 'init'

Taxonomy registration code:

```
add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'create_taxonomy' ) );
public function create_taxonomy() {
    $keyword_args = array(
    'labels' => array(
        'name'              => 'Keywords',
        'singular_name'     => 'Keyword',
        'search_items'      => 'Search Keywords',
        'all_items'         => 'All Keywords',
        'edit_item'         => 'Edit Keyword',
        'update_item'       => 'Update Keyword',
        'add_new_item'      => 'Add New Keyword',
        'new_item_name'     => 'New Keyword Name',
        'popular_items' => 'Popular Acresses',
        'not_found'     => 'No Keywords found',
        'menu_name'         => 'Keywords',
    ),
    'hierarchical'  => false,
    'public'  => true
    );   
    register_taxonomy('keyword', array('post'), $keyword_args);
}
```

Code outside WordPress that uses get_the_terms():

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('../../../../wp-blog-header.php' );

$terms = get_the_terms( 284, 'keyword' );
var_dump($terms);
```

Comment: At what hook do you register your taxonomies?, It happens, if you are trying to get the terms for taxonomy before it is being registered. You need to check your code to make sure you register taxonomy before you query terms for it.

Comment: Why do you ask the same question in both StakOverflow and WPSE? If the question is WP specific ask here, otherwise in SO.

Comment: @sven, I have registered the taxonomy at 'init'

Comment: provide the code you are using for registering taxonomy and for getting the terms.

Comment: @sven I have updated the question with code snippets.

Comment: Solved it! I had earlier registered taxonomy in admin init hook, so was not accessible outside.